# MongoDB Document Validation always fails

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, mongodb

I am trying to add in validation on my MongoDB server and everything I give it fails document validation.

The most common error I keep getting:

`details: { operatorName: '$and', clausesNotSatisfied: [Array] }`

The validation logic I'm using:

```
{
  title: 'Facebook Conversation',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    participants: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: 'string'
          }
        },
        required: [
          'name'
        ],
        additionalProperties: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          sender_name: {
            type: 'string'
          },
          timestamp_ms: {
            type: 'number'
          },
          content: {
            type: 'string'
          },
          type: {
            type: 'string'
          },
          photos: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                uri: {
                  type: 'string'
                },
                creation_timestamp: {
                  type: 'number'
                }
              },
              required: [
                'uri',
                'creation_timestamp'
              ]
            }
          },
          ip: {
            type: 'string'
          },
          sticker: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              uri: {
                type: 'string'
              }
            }
          },
          payment_info: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              amount: {
                type: 'number'
              },
              currency: {
                type: 'string'
              },
              creationTime: {
                type: 'number'
              },
              completedTime: {
                type: 'number'
              },
              senderName: {
                type: 'string'
              },
              receiverName: {
                type: 'string'
              }
            }
          },
          call_duration: {
            type: 'number'
          },
          missed: {
            type: 'boolean'
          },
          gifs: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                uri: {
                  type: 'string'
                }
              },
              required: [
                'uri'
              ]
            }
          },
          share: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              link: {
                type: 'string'
              },
              share_text: {
                type: 'string'
              }
            }
          },
          videos: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                uri: {
                  type: 'string'
                },
                creation_timestamp: {
                  type: 'number'
                },
                thumbnail: {
                  type: 'object',
                  properties: {
                    uri: {
                      type: 'string'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              required: [
                'uri',
                'creation_timestamp',
                'thumbnail'
              ]
            }
          },
          reactions: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                reaction: {
                  type: 'string'
                },
                actor: {
                  type: 'string'
                }
              },
              required: [
                'reaction',
                'actor'
              ]
            }
          },
          audio_files: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                uri: {
                  type: 'string'
                },
                creation_timestamp: {
                  type: 'number'
                }
              },
              required: [
                'uri',
                'creation_timestamp'
              ]
            }
          },
          users: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                name: {
                  type: 'string'
                }
              },
              required: [
                'name'
              ]
            }
          },
          files: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                uri: {
                  type: 'string'
                },
                creation_timestamp: {
                  type: 'number'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        required: [
          'sender_name',
          'timestamp_ms',
          'content'
        ]
      }
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    is_still_participant: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    thread_type: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    thread_path: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

An example of a JSON file that fails document validation:

```
{
    "participants": [
      {
        "name": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Me"
      }
    ],
    "messages": [
      {
        "sender_name": "Person",
        "timestamp_ms": 1550000006885,
        "content": "Message content",
        "type": "Generic"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Person",
    "is_still_participant": true,
    "thread_type": "Regular",
    "thread_path": "inbox/Person"
  }
```

Typescript code I'm using:

```
apiRouter.post("/", async (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    try {
        let newConversation = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        const result = await collections.conversations?.insertOne(newConversation);
        result
            ? res.status(201).send(`Successfully created a new conversation`)
            : res.status(500).send("Failed to create a new conversation.");
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(400).send(error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Unexpected error', error);
        }

    }
});
```

If I use JSON.stringify on the req.body, I get this error:

`Cannot create property '_id' on string`

So I'm really confused as to what I'm doing wrong, I actually allowed JSON to pass without validation and then exported the schema in Compass and used that as validation logic and that doesn't work as well. But maybe that's not meant to be used as validation logic and that's why. But if anybody could help me figure this out, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Why would you use `JSON.stringify` on `req.body`?

Comment: I forgot to edit that out of the code snippet, it was in an attempt to see if MongoDB was just receiving the data wrong. I tried JSON.parse as well. But I don't think that was the issue because if I turn validation off, it has no issue inserting the document, and the content is correct, but it shows as a sample document that fails validation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, when I added the JSON as validation in MongoDB, I used Compass and it didn't accept the $schema tag and when I removed it, it allowed me to apply it, so I assumed I entered everything correctly.

However I was looking around MongoDB's website to see examples of JSON schemas and I noticed they enclosed it with `$jsonSchema: {}`, they were using the shell so I assumed that's why. But I decided to try it and finally documents are successfully validating!